# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/uploadprogress.so'

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/uploadprogress.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/uploadprogress.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I am getting above error on ubuntu 14.04 while installing --

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"
```

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com